# Three.JS rotate projection so that the y axis becomes the z-axis

Tags: 3d, three.js, projection-matrix

Traditionally, in 3D projections, the Y-axis is the axis that represents "up and down". I learned to think of it, with other engines, as that axis being the Z-axis. What I was wondering was whether there is a way in [Three.JS](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) to make the Z-axis the "up/down" axis. If so, are there any consequences to it?

Here is a diagram of what I want:
[image]

Comment: To me it seems the picture on the right has "x" and "y" in wrong positions. Shouldn't they be swapped?

Comment: Could you point me to where I could read more about this convention? I've never faced it :-/

Comment: @Arman did you find any solution to how it would work if I wanted to have the x and y axis swapped afterwards?

Comment: @filip how do you mean? This picture is not a rotation of the axes, it is a mirror of "traditional" if you want to mirror things, I think you can scale them dimensionally to a negative number.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could just change the camera rather than the entire coordinate system. For example:

```
var WIDTH = 1024;
var HEIGHT = 768;
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
var ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
var NEAR = 0.1;
var FAR = 10000;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
camera.position.z = 300;
camera.up = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
scene.add(camera);
```

This changes the `up` vector for the camera to use Z-UP.

---

**EDIT**:

To illustrate an example, here's the jsfiddle you created slightly modified to call `lookAt` after setting the `up` vector: http://jsfiddle.net/NycWc/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't have time to test it now but will try soon. Does that have any consequences on other camera methods? Will I still be able to use `lookAt` normally and such?

Comment: Hmm, I would think that lookAt would still work, since it uses the camera's up vector: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/cameras/Camera.js#L32

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I'd expect the camera to go up, instead it seems to left http://jsfiddle.net/NycWc/

Comment: You have to call the ``lookAt`` *after* setting the ``up`` vector: http://jsfiddle.net/NycWc/1/

Comment: If you read this 9 year old answer take note it does not apply for newest releases of Threejs. Please refer to the `THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp` answer below

Answer (score 23):

The following will achieve your desired result

```
THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp.set(0, 0, 1);
```

According to the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.DefaultUp)

> .DefaultUp : Vector3
>
> The default up direction for objects, also used as the default position for DirectionalLight, HemisphereLight and Spotlight (which creates lights shining from the top down).
>   Set to ( 0, 1, 0 ) by default.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, the accepted one just "hacks" the camera top value rather than whole coordinate system (affects all objects) which OP requested.

Comment: X and Y will be swapped, though.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue with an object.  Here's how I fixed it.

```
object.rotation.z = 90 * Math.PI/180;
object.rotation.x = -90 * Math.PI/180;
```

This took changed it's orientation in just the way you're asking.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to change the whole coordinate system so that changing the position y and z will make the changes I described.

Comment: This solution helped me.. Thanks

Answer (score -4):

The xyz coordinate frame should always be set up with the right hand rule. Creating your own convention is simply not such a good plan and will cause a lot of confusion. You can rotate the coordinate frame at will but don't change the direction of the axis. If you really want to do what you display you can make an x,y,-z coordinate frame.